# Response time for websockets using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter for performance testing of my application. I am testing the websocket component and for that I am using plugins (Peter Doornbosch and Maceij Zaleski)

I am getting proper response back from websocket but I am stuck in finding out the response time of websocket component. I am using the listener 'View result tree' and it gives me back 'Load Time' but the value of this field varies with response timeout.

For ex : If I give response timeout as 1000 ms , the result comes like (1000 + few ms )

If I give response timeout as 500 ms , the result comes like (500 + few ms)

Please let me know if there is any way to find out the accurate response time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLNat.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKdKi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BobAZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from the screenshots:

1. You're using the [plugin from Maceij Zaleski](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler)
2. It [reads from the stream for the specified amount of time](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/blob/fb3e353709aaa9733dc481f2e227aeb4a777d29d/src/main/java/JMeter/plugins/functional/samplers/websocket/ServiceSocket.java#L155)

If you're interested in getting the timings for reading a single message - I would suggest switching to `WebSocket Single Read Sampler` from Peter Doornbosch

[image]

More information:

- [Single read sample.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Single%20read%20sample.jmx) example test plan
- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response.